# How do I use a key-chord combination as a prefix binding?

Tags: emacs

The `key-chord-mode` allows me to bind a simultaneous press of two keys to a command. This is great, but I'd like the simultaneous press of a certain combination of keys to enter a mode in which an extra key (or keys) is expected, similar to what happens when I press `C-c` or `C-x`.

Basically, I'd like to bind a function to something like `ab l` or `ab w`, where a simultaneous press of `ab` behaves like a modifier and `l` or `w` determine the final function to call.

How can I do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with `key-chord-mode`? How can you press `j` two times sumultaneously?

Comment: @Chris: I've modified the example in the hopes of removing any ambiguity. In addition to allowing binding a function to a simultaneous press of two different keys, `key-chord-mode` also allows binding a function to a quick chain of two key presses (such as `jj`).

Comment: liszt: Note that key "modifiers" are the likes of Ctrl, Meta, Hyper, Super (keys which must be pressed *simultaneously* with the key they modify). Bindings like `C-x` (which form the start of a longer sequence of key strokes) are known as "prefix bindings".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I'm not familiar with `key-cord` specifically, the normal solution is simply to replace a command with a key-map. From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequence-Input.html):

> 21.8.1 Key Sequence Input
>
> The command loop reads input a key sequence at a time, by calling
>   read-key-sequence. Lisp programs can also call this function; for
>   example, describe-key uses it to read the key to describe. — Function:
>   read-key-sequence prompt &optional continue-echo dont-downcase-last
>   switch-frame-ok command-loop
>
> ```
> This function reads a key sequence and returns it as a string or vector. It keeps reading events until it has accumulated a complete
> ```
>
> key sequence; that is, enough to specify a non-prefix command using
>   the currently active keymaps. (Remember that a key sequence that
>   starts with a mouse event is read using the keymaps of the buffer in
>   the window that the mouse was in, not the current buffer.)

You can create a prefix key-map by making a new sparse keymap, and defining keys into it:

```
(let ((sub-keymap (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key sub-keymap "a" (lambda () (interactive) (message "my nested subcommand a")))
  (define-key sub-keymap "b" (lambda () (interactive) (message "my nested subcommand b")))
  (global-set-key [C-f9] sub-keymap))
```

When you press `[C-f9]`, you will be in 'sub-keymap' and you may press 'a' or 'b' to see the results.

So I would expect that you can achieve what you want by replacing the last line in my example with something like:

```
(key-chord-define-global "ab"   sub-keymap)
```